# How to clone object with keys from an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say I'm having an object and interface

```
type A {
  one: string,
  two: number,
  three: string | undefined
}

const a: A = { one: 'test', two: 1, three: 'test'};

type B {
  one: string,
  three: number,
  four: number
}
```

I want to create an object called `B`, which will clone from `A`, but with **common keys** and **having the same type**

So I want something like a function that when i input objectA and typeB, it will help me return `B = {one: 'test'}`

Thanks

Comment: have you tried this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-clonedeep-method/ lodash is a good library for operation on object

Comment: `const B = ({one} = A)`

Comment: @bharatpatel thanks for the suggestion, this look great but im also looking for a native typescript solution

Comment: define your type as class and during copying you can iterate over prototype

Comment: @StackSlave this only works specifically if I know the key 'one' . I wanna have a more general solution

Comment: the question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard solution for this as below

`const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`

or

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a);
```

This will clone the object **a** and will not contain any reference of Object **a** into Object **b** after assigned.

[For other options refer](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use a native typescript solution, you can use [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to pick out properties from `A` to `B`

```
type A = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
  three: string | undefined;
};

type B = Pick<A, "one">;

const b: B = {
  one: 'test'
};

const b2: B = {
  one: 'test'
  two: 'test'; // u'll get a warning
};
```

Comment: hi, this requires me to know the 'one' keyword, and I actually looking for a function to help me create the object